# How do you export a method in a CIL DLL so that a native program can call it?

Tags: .net, pinvoke, cil

I have reviewed ECMA 335 and I have only found a reference to the `.export` keyword which seems promising but has very little documentation. I have found similar questions on StackOverflow with respect to doing this in C#. However, none of that has lead me anywhere useful so far.

The bottom line is: I have a CIL DLL and I want to invoke some of its static methods from a native C++ application.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In newer versions of ILAsm, you can simply do:

```
.method public static void Foo ()
{
    .export [1]

    // code ...
}
```

This exports Foo at index 1 in the export table. Export ordinals should be unique and sequential.

In older versions, you'd have to do:

```
.data vt = int32 (0) [n]
.vtfixup [n] int32 fromunmanaged at vt

.method public static void Foo ()
{
    .vtentry 1:1
    .export [1]

    // code ...
}
```

(Where 'n' is the amount of exports you want.)

The `.vtentry` indicates which vtable:slot to store the method in. (Table IDs are sequential, and therefore depend on declaration order.)

Newer ILAsms do all this work for you, provided that you don't use the export table for anything else.

Do note that all of this is very unportable.

Answer (score 1):

You have to expose your dll as a com dll. Com does the work of doing the native to .net interop. You can't run IL code in anything but the .net VM.

Comment: As Zor's solution shows, it is possible without COM craziness.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but ilasm still generates a PE MSIL file, still not suitable for calling from a native application. You still need a .net VM to execute the code.

Comment: Managed code cannot magically run without a VM even if called via COM. My solution simply exports managed methods such that, when they are called from native code, the .NET VM steps in and executes the managed code, and then returns to the native code.

Answer (score 0):

So far, based on my experiments, just adding .export [n] without any other gunk is sufficient only when the method does not have any arguments.  I started with a small library of trivial functions, like

```
[DllExport]
public static double fooz(double arg) {
    return arg + 42;
}

[DllExport]
public static int foo0(int arg) {
    return arg + 42;
}

[DllExport]
public static ulong foo1(ulong arg) {
    return arg + 42;
}
```

and with just an `.export` saw that my functions did not crash, but were ignoring their arguments.

Have a look at using UnmanagedExports by Robert Giesecke, available as a Nuget package in Visual Studio.  I've found it to be rather temperamental and delicate where unless I got the configuration right from the very beginning, sometimes it would not build the Debug or place it instead in Release, etc.  There are other iterations by others plus some further development, all visible from the Nuget menu.  I started with the simplest one and tried it with VS2015, VS2017, and VS2019.  When you have a DLL, you can then examine it more closely with the IL disassembler, `ildasm.`

First compile this as a usual C# DLL, no [DllExport], be sure to set the solution configuration (Debug, x64) accordingly.  Then go in and have a look under the hood using ildasm.  Start with something small.

Next step is to try again with [DllExport] and have a look at what changes were made.  I used WinMerge.  It is essential to understand exactly what this tool does and not blindly use it and expect everything to automagically work.

As for function arguments, for testing, I stuck with the simplest things and tested the DLLs first with VBA.

```
Declare PtrSafe Function fooz Lib "C:\Users\bill\source\repos\Test3\bin\x86\Debug\Test3.dll" (ByVal arg As Double) As Double
```

As my Excel is only 32 bits, the companion DLL must be of the same bit-ness, hence x86.

If you have arguments and results of any complexity (byte[] and beyond) you'll need to employ some sort of marshalling, which I haven't quite mastered yet.  Think byte array of JSON or MsgPack or one of those.

Next step is to see if this works with .Net Core under Linux.

Lastly, I would not touch COM with a 39.5 foot (12.04m) pole, mostly to avoid vendor schlock.