# LoadLibrary fails with error 203: The system could not find the environment option that was entered

Tags: c++, windows, interop

I created a c# class library. I want to load this .dll in my win32 console application, because I have exported one function from the c# class library to unmanaged code and I don't know of any other way to call that function now. 
But LoadLibraryA is giving me that error, what can it mean? Googling didn't help me at all.

Used this to export the function to unmanaged:
https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports#TOC-C-:

**EDIT:** Here is the code, sorry I didn't include it at first because it's as barebones as it gets:

```
using System;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ManagedLibrary
{
    public class Test
    {
        [DllExport(CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static void test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HI");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is LoadLibrary actually failing or are you calling GetLastError whether it fails or not?

Comment: It would be nice to see your native code, the code that calls LoadLibrary and checks the return value, and then calls GetLastError.

Comment: David, Carey, I added more info and all the code I use. The dll is in the same folder as the .exe as you can see. I removed the GetLastError call, but I did it right after LoadLibrary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the unmanaged exports nuget tool doesn't work for me, the .dll loading errors were mostly obscure and unrelated as it seems (although I did switch to my home computer now)
After I have manually added the exports IL statement as described here:[How do you export a method in a CIL DLL so that a native program can call it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957970/how-do-you-export-a-method-in-a-cil-dll-so-that-a-native-program-can-call-it) I was able to call the C# code just fine.