# DllExport from C# .Net application

Tags: c#, .net, dll, dllexport

Is there a simple way of exporting a symbol/constant from .Net 5+ applications without having to install third-party NuGets? I'd like to do something like:

```cs
[DllExport("MySymbol")]
public static int MySymbol = 1234;
```

This would be the equivalent of exporting a symbol from C++:

```cpp
extern "C" { __declspec(dllexport) extern const UINT MySymbol = 1234; }
```

I found some repositories that add unmanaged export capability, but I don't need to export classes or methods, but just a symbol, so if there's a way of doing this without adding a thousand lines of code or extra dependencies, it would be great.

Comment: There is no `DllExportAttribiute` *without having to install...*

Comment: Yes, obviously there's none! My question is if someone could point me to a direction I can  find info on how to do it. Like any documentation or blogs to write as little code as I can in order to do it.

Comment: You mean, you are asking for some resources recommendation?

Comment: You presumably just want to here "No there is nothing build in". And the easiest way to solve that is to use a solution that someone else has already implemented. Thats often a Nuget. There is nothing else the ones implementing the nuget package wheren't just ignorant to the "easy" thing. Complete Alternative use a language understanding managed code. You said C++ so you may want to look at C++/CLR.

Comment: yes, anything that would help me to do the thing that I described in my OP.

Comment: You could also use COM interop to access a C# dll from C/C++. It's all doable, requires a bit more effort than the other way round.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you export a method in a CIL DLL so that a native program can call it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957970/how-do-you-export-a-method-in-a-cil-dll-so-that-a-native-program-can-call-it)

Comment: ildasm.exe, change the MSIL to add a `.export` or `.vtfixup` entries, then use ilasm.exe to recompile

Comment: @Charlieface, looks like something worth investigating. Need some time to figure out if and how it could work for static variables. Thanks anyway. It's refreshing to see someone who's actually trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer I'd have liked to see: .Net core applications are launched using a native host. Therefore, even if you manage to export symbols from the .Net assembly, they wouldn't be exported by the main executable of the running process.

In order to export symbols, the default native host needs to be replaced by a custom host using [this documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/features/native-hosting.md). In this case, the manifest and app icon/resources may also need to be included by the developer, since the native host is no longer automatically generated.